# Production of oxirane mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Regarding oxirane production developed by Wurtz, is there an accepted mechanism?
[image]

I carried out a research but couldn't find anything. My approach was this [image]
Is that correct?

Comment: The only additional clue, I've found, is that heat must be applied for the reaction to take place.

Comment: Deprotonate using hydroxide before doing an intramolecular SN2

Comment: I see. So there is no way something like what I suggested could take place, right?

Comment: You should not make a primary unstabilized carbocation unless you have a very good reason to do so. The short answer here is, no, I don't believe this is a likely mechanism for the reaction.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81896/stereochemistry-synthesis-of-an-epoxide

Comment: If you were thinking of running the reaction using Wurtz conditions with elemental sodium then the sodium will react with the OH preferentially.